# hdfs.DataStreamer: Exception in createBlockOutputStream

Tags: java, hadoop

below is my hdfs client code to copy local file to hdfs
the below client code is being run on windows with winutils.exe.
its connecting to remote hdfs cluster running on linux ( via port-forwarding )

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String nameserviceId = "apache-hadoop-namenode";

    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://" + nameserviceId);
    conf.set("dfs.nameservices", "apache-hadoop-namenode");
    conf.set("dfs.ha.namenodes.apache-hadoop-namenode", "nn1,nn2");
    conf.set("dfs.namenode.rpc-address.apache-hadoop-namenode.nn1" ,"127.0.0.1:10445");
    conf.set("dfs.namenode.rpc-address.apache-hadoop-namenode.nn2" ,"127.0.0.1:10446");

    conf.set("dfs.namenode.http-address.apache-hadoop-namenode.n1", "127.0.0.1:10443");
    conf.set("dfs.namenode.http-address.apache-hadoop-namenode.n2", "127.0.0.1:10444");

    conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
    conf.set("fs.file.impl", LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
    conf.set("dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.apache-hadoop-namenode",
            "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider");

    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    writeToHDFS(fs);
}
public static void writeToHDFS(FileSystem fs) throws IOException {
    String fileName = "200MB.txt";
    Path hdfsWritePath = new Path("/app/"+fileName);
    FSDataOutputStream fsDataOutputStream = fs.create(hdfsWritePath);
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("200MB.txt");
    System.out.println("copying files now");
    IOUtils.copy(in,fsDataOutputStream);
    System.out.println("copied successfully");
}
```

Below is the logs when i build this.

```
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Reload4jLoggerFactory]
copying files now
22/09/01 10:47:07 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1073741845_1022
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1728)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:713)
22/09/01 10:47:07 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Abandoning BP-818724710-10.131.0.252-1661971419595:blk_1073741845_1022
22/09/01 10:47:07 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.128.3.164:9866,DS-ed4c53d2-7a36-4591-a283-7cc1bb37dfd7,DISK]
22/09/01 10:47:28 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1073741846_1023
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1728)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:713)


org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /app/200MB.txt could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2960)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:904)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1043)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:971)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2976)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:129)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:530)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1088)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1915)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:713)
```

Comment: its saying connection timed out, can anyone tell which timeout its talking about

Comment: i reduced the file size copy to 1MB , it was able to copy , but in hadoop UI, i see the size as 0

Comment: `3 node(s) are excluded in this operation` - Your namenode(s) don't know how to write to the datanodes... So, your client added metadata to the namenode, but then the namenode didn't communicate the datanode addresses properly back to the client for data to actually be written. Besides, why re-do logic of `hadoop fs -put` command?

Comment: I wanted to check retry logic from client , if in case i kill one of the namenode and want to do verification if there is a data loss or not?
please let me know if there is any other way to verify data loss of huge files like 1GB

Comment: IMO, 1GB is still small (ex. fits on a few dollar flash drive), but I dont know about retry logic. It's possible the blocks will be corrupt as the failover is not immediate, but none of that is related to your error. As mentioned, it seems the namenode doesn't know about your datanodes. There is source code for [`RetriableCommand`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-distcp/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/tools/util/RetriableCommand.java)